# How do you remotely connect to a docker daemon on Windows WSL2 backend from another machine's docker client through a VPN?

Tags: docker, wsl2, podman

I tried setting hosts array in the Docker Engine configuration (json) file inside the Docker Desktop interface. The VM did start successfully for 127.0.0.1.

Tho **Docker Desktop UI is stuck spinning** after "Apply & Restart" button was pressed when set to a tailscale **VPN network adapter IP address**.

There isn't many example of this and if someone can confirm they got it to work it would be great.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is inaccessible to any machine other than the host.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is accessible to any machine, but its a loopback address so it's just another way to refer to itself https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: It seems to me that the OP is aware of the 127.0.0.1 limitation, since it's stated that the VM is working fine with 127.0.01, but when set to the IP address they *need*, it isn't accessible.

Comment: When you say it *"won't boot"* with that IP, is there any error message?

Comment: No errors texts that I am aware of.. it's just stuck spinning after Docker Desktop's "Apply & Restart"